# How to filter and sort excel table(listobject) in protected sheet

Tags: excel, listobject

It's possible to filter and sort a table (listobject) in protected Excel sheet with or without VBA?

**This VBA code allows to filter but does not allow to sort**

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
```

**This VBA code does not to filter and sort !!!**

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="tt"
```

Comment: You could read the range into a VBA array, and sort and filter it there. But not within the protected sheet itself, if those methods are disabled.

Comment: I just find out that if a sheet is protected and set a password you can filter but you cannot sort, but if you try to protect it using vba without setting a password it does the same. If you set a password in vba it does not allows either to work!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problems, so I share it to you.

The idea is to have a button to unprotect the sheet and allow filtering and sorting.
When the sheet is unprotected and you click somewhere different from the table header, the sheet is protected again.

**Put this code in the worksheet module**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ol As ListObject

    Set ol = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)

    ' This sets the Target to only one cell range when sort is used
    Dim cnt As Integer: cnt = Target.CountLarge
    If cnt > 1 Then Set Target = Range(Split(Target.Address, ":")(0))

    ' It protects the sheet if different cell from table header is selected
    If Intersect(Target, ol.HeaderRowRange) Is Nothing And editMode Then
        Call wsProtect
    End If

    Set ol = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Put this code in a standard module**

```
Option Explicit

Public editMode As Boolean

Sub wsProtect()
    editMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="tt", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub

Sub wsUnProtect()
    editMode = True

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="tt"
End Sub

Sub enableEditMode()
    wsUnProtect
End Sub
```